# SQL query for inserting a new node in a table using the nested set model fails to execute

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, nested-set-model

I'm currently working with the nested set model and i've read the article from the MySQL site ([Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)).

I got the following query directly from the article:

```
LOCK TABLE categories WRITE;

SELECT @myRight := right FROM categories WHERE name = ?;

UPDATE categories SET right = right + 2 WHERE right > @myRight;
UPDATE categories SET left = lft + 2 WHERE left > @myRight;

INSERT INTO categories (name, left, right) VALUES(?, @myRight + 1, @myRight + 2);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

I'm using PHP and MySQLi functions to execute this statement like this:

```
if (false !== $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', 'services', 'hosting');
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

The following code produces a syntax error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @myRight := right FROM categories WHERE name = ?; UPDATE categories SET righ' at line 3
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MySQLi::prepare` only works on single-statement queries.

You should break your query into a series of single statements, prepare those preparable and issue them independently.

Alternatively, wrap your batch into a stored procedure and call it.

Comment: So do I need mysqli::multi-query() then?, also stored procedures is not an option.

Comment: @Melvin: either that (note that it cannot be prepared), or a stored proc.